# Cannot set userData property of threejs MeshBasicMaterial instance

Tags: typescript, three.js

I'm getting a TypeScript error when attempting to set the `userData` property of a `MeshBasicMaterial` instance at instantiation time.

For example:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
...
const customUserData = {
  ...
};
const myMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xf7f7f7, 
  transparent: true, 
  opacity: 1, 
  side: THREE.BackSide,
  userData: myCustomUserData
});
```

This returns the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ color: number; transparent: true; opacity: number; side: THREE.Side; userData: null; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MeshBasicMaterialParameters'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'userData' does not exist in type 'MeshBasicMaterialParameters'.  TS2345
```

However, when I investigate the type definition of `MeshBasicMaterial`, it extends `Material`:

```
export class MeshBasicMaterial extends Material { ... }
```

The `Material` class, in turn, specifies a `userData` property:

```
export class Material extends EventDispatcher {
    // ...
    userData: any;
    // ...
}
```

However, specifying the `userData` property outside the class instantiation works:

```
let myMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({...});
myMaterial.userData = myCustomUserData;
```

Shouldn't `MeshBasicMaterial` have inherited a `userData` property from `Material`, or am I missing something obvious about this? (It is probably do with the `MeshBasicMaterialParameters` type, but it's not clear why this type is used or preventing inheritance of properties from `Material`.)

Comment: What's the value of myCustomUserData?

Comment: It's just some key and value pairs useful to me, but to answer your question, anything I put in here will fail: the error seems to come from specifying `userData` in the material properties at instantiation time.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you found a missing type definition!

You're right, when looking at the `Material` class definition file, [it has a `.userData` property](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/materials/Material.d.ts#L339). This means that setting it like `material.userData = xxx;` should work fine.

However, when initiating the material with `new THREE.Material(props);`, the `props` argument you pass uses a similar but different structure, declared in the interface `MaterialParameters`, and if [you look at what that includes on line 16](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/materials/Material.d.ts#L16), it's missing `userData`.

The same bug applies to `MeshBasicMaterialParameters`, since it extends `MaterialParameters`.

As a quick solution, I recommend you just set it with `material.userData = xxx;`, and file a Github issue so it can be fixed in future releases. As a more complicated solution, you could create your own declaration file, [and do a Merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) with the `MaterialParameters` interface to include `.userData`.

Comment: If you do open a GitHub issue, send me the link, I could fix it quickly for the next release.

Comment: Hey, many thanks. Just wasn't sure if I missed something about how I am using this. Here is a link to the issue I filed: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/20621

Comment: (I'm afraid I can't award you the bounty, just yet, but I will do so when the time window opens up.)